# Ошибка компиляции простого приложения

Tags: xcode, swift

Пытаюсь закомпилировать простое приложение с одной кнопкой и выводом, при нажатии, ее значения в лог, вот код:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBAction func TouchDigit(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let digit = sender.currentTitle
        print("\(digit) was be called")
    }


}
```

Но к моему сожалению прилетает вот такой целый лог ошибок:

```
2017-10-12 17:41:23.972 CalculatorStanford[27870:11130726] -[CalculatorStanford.ViewController Button:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f99fed07ac0
2017-10-12 17:41:23.980 CalculatorStanford[27870:11130726] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[CalculatorStanford.ViewController Button:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f99fed07ac0'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000111275b0b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010e51b141 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001112e5134 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001111fc840 ___forwarding___ + 1024
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001111fc3b8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   UIKit                               0x000000010e9eed82 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 83
    6   UIKit                               0x000000010eb735ac -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
    7   UIKit                               0x000000010eb738c7 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 450
    8   UIKit                               0x000000010eb72802 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 618
    9   UIKit                               0x000000010ea5c7ea -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 2707
    10  UIKit                               0x000000010ea5df00 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 4114
    11  UIKit                               0x000000010ea0aa84 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 352
    12  UIKit                               0x000000010f1ee5d4 __dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue + 2926
    13  UIKit                               0x000000010f1e6532 __handleEventQueue + 1122
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x000000011121bc01 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001112010cf __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 527
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001112005ff __CFRunLoopRun + 911
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000111200016 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 406
    18  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000113180a24 GSEventRunModal + 62
    19  UIKit                               0x000000010e9ed134 UIApplicationMain + 159
    20  CalculatorStanford                  0x000000010df44b57 main + 55
    21  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000011221565d start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Учусь это делать по курсам Оксфордского университета, но там таких ошибок почему-то нет. В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

проверьте аутлеты в сториборде (ваша кнопка вызывает метод которого нет в контроллере, может вы поменяли название метода или что-то в таком духе)[image]

по вашему коду у вас должно быть такое :
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В коде я навожу на точку и оно подсвечивает кнопку, я так понимаю, что они соединены одним методом

Comment: посмотрите второй скрин

Comment: и попробуйте удалить связь и связать заново

Comment: Я вам бесконечно благодарен. У меня по другому немного выглядит, может другая версия xcode(не обновлял еще). Оно находилось в Sent Events, но после новой связи, все заработало.